# How to calculate number of matrices contains 2-zeroes lines

Tags: combinatorics, matrices

Consider a matrix $A \in Mat_{n \times n}(\{0,1\})$. Now we want to calculate the amount of 2-zeroes lines in matrix, i.e. consider  a matrix $A : $

\begin{pmatrix}
  1& 1 & 1 & \dots & 1\\
  0 & 0 & 0  &\dots & 0\\
  0 & 0 & 0  &\dots & 0\\
  1& 1 & 1 & \dots & 1\\
  \dots & \dots & \dots &\dots &\dots
\end{pmatrix}

This matrix has two consecutive lines containing zeroes.

We need to find number of matrix from $Mat_{n \times n}(\{0,1\})$ containig such propertie.

Also I need to mention that this matrices are appropriates :

$\begin{pmatrix}
  1& 1 & 1 & \dots & 1\\
  0 & 0 & 0  &\dots & 0\\
  0 & 0 & 0  &\dots & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 0  &\dots & 0\\
  \dots & \dots & \dots &\dots &\dots
\end{pmatrix}$ ,$\begin{pmatrix}
  1& 1 & 0 & \dots & 1\\
  0 & 0 & 0  &\dots & 0\\
  0 & 0 & 0  &\dots & 0\\
    1 & 1 & 0  &\dots & 1\\
  \dots & \dots & \dots &\dots &\dots
\end{pmatrix}$ ,  $\begin{pmatrix}
  1& 0 & 0 & 1& \dots & 1\\
  1 & 0 & 0 &1  &\dots & 1\\
  1 & 0 & 0  &1&\dots & 1\\
    1 & 0 & 0 &1 &\dots & 1\\
  \dots & \dots &\dots& \dots &\dots &\dots
\end{pmatrix}$,

So it doesn't matter where should be the 2-lines of zeroes in row or in column, or it doesn't matter it 3-lines the main property that **there should be at least one 2-zeroes line.**

I've tried to calculate it by step, i.e. :

$\displaystyle \sum_{k=2n}^{4n-5}2(n-1)\binom{n^{2}}{k-2n} + \sum_{k=4n-4}^{...}\binom{n^{2}}{k-2n}-\dots$ this dotes arise from repeating combination. This is the problem I've stuck. Any ideas ?

*Edit* :
All valid matrices for $n = 3$

$\begin{pmatrix}
  1& 1 & 1 \\
  0& 0 & 0 \\
  0& 0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}$ , $\begin{pmatrix}
  0& 1 & 1 \\
  0& 0 & 0 \\
  0& 0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}$ , $\begin{pmatrix}
  1& 0 & 1 \\
  0& 0 & 0 \\
  0& 0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}$ , $\begin{pmatrix}
  1& 1 & 0 \\
  0& 0 & 0 \\
  0& 0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}$ , $\begin{pmatrix}
  0& 0 & 1 \\
  0& 0 & 0 \\
  0& 0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}$ , $\begin{pmatrix}
  1& 0 & 0 \\
  0& 0 & 0 \\
  0& 0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}$ , $\begin{pmatrix}
  0& 1 & 0 \\
  0& 0 & 0 \\
  0& 0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}$, $\begin{pmatrix}
  0& 0 & 0 \\
  0& 0 & 0 \\
  0& 0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}$ , $\begin{pmatrix}
  0& 0 & 1 \\
  0& 0 & 1 \\
  0& 0 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}$ , $\begin{pmatrix}
  0& 0 & 0 \\
  0& 0 & 1 \\
  0& 0 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}$ , $\begin{pmatrix}
  0& 0 & 1 \\
  0& 0 & 0 \\
  0& 0 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}$ , $\begin{pmatrix}
  0& 0 & 1 \\
  0& 0 & 1 \\
  0& 0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}$ , $\begin{pmatrix}
  0& 0 & 0 \\
  0& 0 & 0 \\
  0& 0 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}$ , $\begin{pmatrix}
  0& 0 & 0 \\
  0& 0 & 1 \\
  0& 0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}$ , $\begin{pmatrix}
  0& 0 & 0 \\
  0& 0 & 0 \\
  1 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}$ , $\begin{pmatrix}
  0& 0 & 0 \\
  0& 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}$ , $\begin{pmatrix}
  0& 0 & 0 \\
  0& 0 & 0 \\
  1 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}$ , $\begin{pmatrix}
  0& 0 & 0 \\
  0& 0 & 0 \\
  1 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}$ , $\begin{pmatrix}
  0& 0 & 0 \\
  0& 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}$ , $\begin{pmatrix}
  0& 0 & 0 \\
  0& 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}$ , $\begin{pmatrix}
  1& 0 & 0 \\
  1& 0 & 0 \\
  1 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}$ , $\begin{pmatrix}
  0& 0 & 0 \\
  1& 0 & 0 \\
  1 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}$ , $\begin{pmatrix}
  1& 0 & 0 \\
  0& 0 & 0 \\
  1 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}$  , $\begin{pmatrix}
  1& 0 & 0 \\
  1& 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}$  , $\begin{pmatrix}
  0& 0 & 0 \\
  1& 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}$ . I guess that's all for $n =3$.

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to count. Are you saying there must be two consecutive zero lines, and all other entries can be chosen arbitrarily? Or must it be true that every number not in a zero line is equal to $1$? Maybe it would clear up my confusion if you listed out all the valid matrices for $n=3$.

Comment: @MikeEarnest added

Comment: This is going to be a complicated inclusion exclusion problem. Add up the matrices which are zero in two particular adjacent lines, subtract the doubly counted matrices, add back in the triple intersections, etc. Ultimately, you will need to be able to answer this question; how many subsets $S$ of $\{1,2,\dots,n-1\}$ of size $i$ have $|S\cup(S+1)|=k$? When performing inclusion exclusion, $i$ will determine the sign, while $k$ determines the number of rows forced to be zero when you suppose rows $i$ and $i+1$ are zero for all $i\in S$.

Comment: @MikeEarnest I've tried to use inclusion exclusion , but it hard to understand the main rule of adding and subtracting

Comment: if you just count matrices with all-zeros in adjacent rows, i think that is not a difficult Inclusion-Exclusion problem.  however, you want matrices with all-zeros in adjacent rows and/or adjacent columns, i think that is a much more tedious I-E problem.  would a solution to the easier problem (just rows) be helpful to you?

Comment: @antkam unfortunatly no.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me suggest a different strategy. I think it is easier to count the complement of the set of matrices you ask for. Say $I_n$ is the number you are interested in, then I will describe how to count $2^{n^2}-I_n$ which is the number of square $n\times n$ matrices with no consecutive zero lines or consecutive zero columns.

Consider such a matrix. Let $m$ be the number of non-zero lines, and $k$ the number of non-zero columns. By removing the $n-m$ zero lines and the $n-k$ zero columns you obtain a $m\times k$ matrix with no zero line and no zero column. Let $J_{m,k}$ be the number of such matrices. To recover $2^{n^2}-I_n$ from the $J_{m,k}$ it suffices to count the ways to insert the zero lines and columns between the non-zero lines/columns or before the first non-zero line/column or after the last non-zero line/column. We thus have 
$$ 2^{n^2}-I_n=\sum_{0\leq m,k \leq n} {k+1 \choose n-k} {m+1 \choose n-m} J_{m,k} $$
Of course, there are a number of zero summands as I wrote it, one can be more precise on the bounds of the indices.

Finally it remains to count $J_{m,k}$. This should be a tractable inclusion-exclusion problem as it amounts to the number of family of $m$ elements of $\{0,1\}^k$, considered as vectors in $\mathbb{R}^k$, such that:

1) no vector is the zero vector (i.e. no zero line)

2) not all vectors lie in a common coordinate hyperplane (i.e. no zero column).

**Edit:** To complete the answer. 
Using inclusion/exclusion to compute $J_{m,k}$ yields
$$ J_{m,k}= \sum_{j=0}^{k} {k \choose j}(-1)^{k-j}(2^j-1)^m $$
hence after rewriting, 
$$ I_n= 2^{n^2}-\sum_{\frac{n-1}{2}<m,k\leq n}\sum_{0\leq i\leq m}\sum_{0\leq j\leq k} {k+1 \choose n-k}{m+1 \choose n-m}{k \choose j}{m \choose i} (-1)^{k+m-i-j}2^{ij} $$ 
It is not clear if the expression can be simplified in any way. The first values are $I_3=25$ (which is consistent with the list above), $I_4=1368$, $I_5=249175$, etc. It does not appear in the OEIS.

Comment: Nice approach. (+1)

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way(idea) to count the set of matrices.For the set of matrices $A \in Mat_{n \times n}(\{0,1\})$, $n>3$, The total number of matrices with minimum two rows of zeroes can be calculated thus...
For each row of $n$ columns, each element has the value $0$ or $1$, with $2$ 
possible values. So, the total number of all possible values for a row is $2^n$.

Consider a now a matrix with two bands, one horizontal and vertical each band containing $4$ rows and $4$ columns respectively.Within the band, the center two rows/columns will all be $0$ (The 2-zeroes). The Two "guardian" rows/columns bordering the center rows/columns *will not* contain *all* zeroes like this..

\begin{pmatrix}
  a_{11}& a_{12} & a_{13} & a_{14} & 0 & 0 & a_{17} & \dots & a_{1n}\\
  a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} & a_{24} & 0 & 0 & a_{27} & \dots & a_{2n}\\
  a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33} & a_{34} & 0 & 0 & a_{37} &\dots & a_{3n}\\
  \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & 0 & 0 & \dots & \dots & \dots\\ 
  a_{61} & a_{62} & a_{63} & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 &  \dots & a_{6n}\\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  0 & 0\\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  0 & 0\\
  a_{91} & a_{92} & a_{93} & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & \dots & a_{9n}\\
  a_{101}& a_{102} & a_{103} & a_{104} & 0 & 0 & a_{107} & \dots & a_{10n}\\
  \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & 0 & 0 & \dots & \dots & \dots\\ 
  a_{n1} & a_{n2} & a_{n3} & a_{n4} & 0 & 0 & a_{n7} & \dots & a_{nn}\\
\end{pmatrix}

Now, guardian rows are rows $6$ and $9$ and the columns are $4$ and $7$. 
All the rest of $a_{ij}$ can be either $1$ or $0$.
Now, how many possible $a_{ij}$ are there? The first row can contain $2^{n-2}$, excluding the column "0-band". Excluding the guardian rows for now, we have $n-4$ rows each containing $2^{n-2}$, $a_{ij}$s and $2(n-4)$, $a_{ij}$s in the guardian rows $6$ and $9$.
So the possible matrices with this "fixed" bands are,

$$2^{n-2} * 2^{n-2} * 2^{n-2}... (n-4) times$$ and,
$$2*2^{n-4}$$ for the guardian rows. 
$$=> 2^{(n-2)(n-4)} + 2^{n-3}$$ possible matrices.
Now, This is for one such fixed configuration of the bands. You can imagine  the bands moving from left to right and from top to bottom. Giving $n-4+1$ ways to position a 4-band in $n$ sized row.
Giving rise to $(n-3)^2$ possible ways to position both. So altogether, in all these positions of the bands we  can have $$(n-3)^2(2^{(n-2)(n-4)} + 2^{n-3})$$ possible matrices. Of course, there is more. We left out The $1$ position there are $2^4 -1 =15$ more. Now, finally the only collapsible case would be all the $a_{ij}$ are $0$ and the guardian $1$ becomes $0$. I guess, you could work it out....:-). Now, I haven't analysed for $n < 4$ and *atleast* $2$-zero scenarios.

Comment: Two aspects: There seems to be some overcounting, since the $a_{i,j}$ which are declared to be freely set to $0$ or $1$ may also form one or more such zero-bands. We also have to consider the situation where we have only consecutive zero rows or only consecutive zero columns.